# If $ab$ is an element of $G$ and $a\ast b=b\ast a$, we say that $a$ and $b$ commute. Suppose 3 and 2 commute. Does $3^{-1}$ and $2^{-1}$ commute

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think it will also commute because it is under multiplication.

Comment: [How to format mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: My friend, you have posted your question in title of it!

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are, since (I took $a=3$ and $b=2$ for clearer presentation)

$a^{-1}b^{-1} = (ba)^{-1} = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$

The point here is the formula $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ (you can check it by hand just applying the definition of inverse and using its unicity) that allows you to apply the hypothesis of commutation on $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see whats the relation to $2$ and $3$, and which group are you talking about anyway?

The following is true in any group $G$, and for any two commuting elements $a,b\in G$:
$$a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}.$$

Answer (score -1):

If $a*b = b*a$ (i.e. $a$ and $b$ commute), then $a*b$ and $b*a$ have the same inverse.  In other words, $(a*b)^{-1} = (b*a)^{-1}$.  But then, by properties of the inverse, this is

$b^{-1}*a^{-1} = (a*b)^{-1} = (b*a)^{-1} = a^{-1}*b^{-1}$

By a similar argument, it can be shown that

$a$ and $b$ commute if and only if $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ commute.

That being said, without knowing what $G$ is, it is unclear if this is the statement you need or not.

Comment: OP may not be working over any group; the question doesn't say.

Comment: Good point.  In that case, it would seem to be entirely impossible to answer the question.  Admittedly, I made that simplifying assumption because of the "abstract algebra" tag.  But without more information, there's not much we can say.